# Tengo un problemas con el php 7 al poner el PDO $pdo -> close();

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, apache

```
require_once "ConexionBD.php";

class UsuariosM extends ConexionBD {
static public function IniciarSesionM($tablaBD, $datosC) {
    $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()-\>prepare("SELECT \* FROM $tablaBD WHERE libreta = :libreta");
    $pdo -\> bindParam(":libreta", $datosC\["libreta"\], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $pdo -\>execute();  
    return $pdo -\> fetch();
    $pdo -\> close(); // <- este es el error  
    $pdo = null;
}
}
```

Estoy siguiendo un tutorialen que se usa la versión PHP 7.3.3 pero yo estoy utilizando 7.4.29. No sé si esa puede ser la causa del problema.

Comment: Al llamar return se termina el tiempo de vida del método y no debería haber nada más abajo.

Comment: Te estaría faltando agregar el mensaje de error que estas recibiendo

Answer (score 3):

[Revisa la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php). Verás que la clase `PDOStatement` no tiene un método `close()`, y ese es el motivo del error. En cambio, la clase sí tiene un método [`closeCursor()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.closecursor.php).

Por otro lado, considera lo que apunta @Marcos en su comentario. Nada de lo que esté después del `return` se ejecutará. Si quieres cerrar recursos, debes antes guardar los datos que obtienes de ese recurso en una variable, luego cerrar el cursor y finalmente hacer `return` de la variable. Cabe decir además que el uso de `null` es redundante para este caso.

Otra cosa que debes cuidar es la *convención de nombre* en tus variables. Esto puede que sea motivo de confusión en tu código, llamas a la variable `$pdo`, que se suele usar para el objeto de conexión, PERO lo que representa `$pdo` en tu contexto NO es la conexión, sino el resultado de [`prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php), que es un `PDOStatement`:

```
$pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablaBD WHERE libreta = :libreta");
```

Para los objetos `PDOStatement` la convención que se suele usar es `$stmt`. Le puedes llamar `$pepitoDeLosPalotes` si quieres, pero el nombrado es importante para comprensión del código y para evitar confusiones.

Así debería funcionar (usaremos una convención adecuada):

```
require_once "ConexionBD.php";

class UsuariosM extends ConexionBD{
    static public function IniciarSesionM($tablaBD, $datosC){
        $stmt = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablaBD WHERE libreta = :libreta");
        $stmt->bindParam(":libreta", $datosC["libreta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
        $stmt->execute();  
        $mData=$stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->closeCursor(); // o $stmt=null; 
        return $mData;
    }
}
```